# Ball in pong only moving on keypress/mouse move

Tags: python, pygame, pong

The ball wont move unless I'm moving my mouse, or clicking one of the buttons I have that are supposed to do things. (i.e. the up and down buttons that are supposed to move the paddle.) Clicking buttons and moving the mouse don't control the direction the Ball moves in- it just gets it to move the way it's supposed to. It will stop moving entirely if I stop moving the mouse or clicking the buttons.

Here's some of the code:

```
while not x:
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
      x = True #quits the game when you press X
    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP: #makes start screen go away
      if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
        gameScreen()
        ball.startMoving() #makes the ball start moving
        start = True

    if start == True:
      gameScreen()

      ball.move() #controls the movement of the ball
      
      ball.show() #makes the ball show up

      p1Paddle.border()
      p1Paddle.show() #make the paddles and ball show up vv

      p2Paddle.border()
      p2Paddle.show()
      

      if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_w: #makes blue paddle go up
          p1Paddle.state = 'up'
          p1Paddle.move()
        
      if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_s: #makes blue paddle go down
          p1Paddle.state = 'down'
          p1Paddle.move()
  
      if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_UP: #makes red paddle go up
          p2Paddle.state = 'up'
          p2Paddle.move()
          
      if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN: #makes red paddle go down
          p2Paddle.state = 'down'
          p2Paddle.move()
    
    pygame.display.update() #updates the screen/window
    clock.tick(30)
```

And here's the code for the ball class.

```
class Ball:
  def __init__(self, screen, colour, posX, posY, radius):
    self.screen = screen
    self.colour = colour
    self.posX = posX
    self.posY = posY
    self.radius = radius
    self.dx = 0
    self.dy = 0
    self.show()

  def show(self):
    pygame.draw.circle(self.screen, self.colour, (self.posX, self.posY), self.radius)

  def startMoving(self):
    self.dx = 15
    self.dy = 5

  def move(self):
    self.posX += self.dx
    self.posY += self.dy
```

Comment: Your indentation seems wrong...surely you don't actually have all your code within the `for event in pygame.event.get():` loop...

Comment: @RandomDavis That's what I have down, yes. I'm really new to code- is it not supposed to be? I've mostly been learning off of tutorials and merging them together based off what I want from each one. I did try changing the indentation, and that makes the window show up blank.

Comment: The issue here is that you're only moving the ball if there are any events that happened between the last loop iteration and the current one; but you should put the code that moves it outside of the event checking loop so that it can run even if there are no events. What's happening is that there are no events being fired if you're not pressing keys, but you designed your program such that the code for moving the ball and paddles runs if there's any events that happened to happen.

Comment: @RandomDavis If I take it out of that loop, the ball starts moving as soon as the window loads, which I don't want. I have a start screen at the beginning, and by the time it goes away, the ball has already reached the edge of the screen. How can i get it to move normally, but only start moving after the user hits enter?

Comment: Based on that behavior, I would guess that `start` is `True` before the application loop even starts. Set it to `False` and that should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would change this code - you'll have to see if it works but I think this is your intention. The comments I added explain my changes. I made it so that all the movement and drawing code for the ball, and the code for drawing the paddle, always runs, regardless of whether or not the user pressed a key or generated some other kind of event.

```py
# -start of application loop-
while not x:
  # -start of event loop- 
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
      x = True
    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
      if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
        gameScreen()
        ball.startMoving()
        start = True

    # only move the paddle if the game is running and the user pressed a key:
    if start == True:
      if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_w:
          p1Paddle.state = 'up'
          p1Paddle.move()

      if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_s:
          p1Paddle.state = 'down'
          p1Paddle.move()

      if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
          p2Paddle.state = 'up'
          p2Paddle.move()

      if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
          p2Paddle.state = 'down'
          p2Paddle.move()
      # -end of event loop-
    
    # Move and draw everything once per application loop,
    # regardless of if the event loop ran:
    if start == True:
      gameScreen()
      ball.move()
      ball.show()
      p1Paddle.border()
      p1Paddle.show()
      p2Paddle.border()
      p2Paddle.show()

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(30)
    # -end of application loop-
```

Comment: I changed the code based on your answer, and the ball still only moves when I press a button or move the mouse. Start is also set to False before the application loop (it has been this way since before I asked the question).

Comment: @n.alha then I recommend using a debugger, like the one in the free program PyCharm ([here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/debugging-your-first-python-application.html)), to step through the code line-by-line and see where the execution starts differing from your expectations. But I strongly suspect that you may have gotten the indentation wrong; since indentation is a critical control flow element of Python, if you got that wrong, it might as well be a completely different program. So, make sure that the code block with `ball.move()` is at the same indentation level as `clock.tick()`.